# Python - convert from hex integer to hex string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a reasonably simple way to convert from a hex integer to a hex string in python?
For example, I have `0xa1b2c3` and I want `"0xa1b2c3"`.  If I use str(), it automatically gets converted to base 10, and then I can't convert it back because it's a string at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just do [`hex()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex)?

```
>>> testNum = 0xa1b2c3
>>> hex(testNum)
    '0xa1b2c3'
>>> test = hex(testNum)
>>> isinstance(test, str)
    True
```

`hex` returns a string representation. See `help(hex)`

```
hex(...)
    hex(number) -> string

    Return the hexadecimal representation of an integer or long integer.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`hex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex):

```
>>> x = 0xa1b2c3
>>> hex(x)
'0xa1b2c3'
```

or [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
>>> "{:#x}".format(x)
'0xa1b2c3'
```

or [format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> format(x, '#x')
'0xa1b2c3'
```

Comment: Use the `format()` function instead; `format(x, '#x')`. No need to have the overhead of the string format parsing too.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like you both answered the same thing at the same time, so I'm accepting his answer because he has a lot less reputation points than you.  Cheers